# How to convert dateTime to UTC?

Tags: apex

How to convert `dateTime` to `UTC` by passing dateTime to a method?

ex. below method

```
public DateTime getUTCDateTime(DateTime dt){

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this. Refer [DateTime](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_datetime.htm) methods for more.

```
public DateTime getUTCDateTime(DateTime dt){
    Datetime GMTDate = Datetime.newInstanceGmt(
                            dt.year(),
                            dt.month(),
                            dt.day(),
                            dt.hour(),
                            dt.minute(),
                            dt.second());
    return GMTDate;
}

System.debug('utc time '+getUTCDateTime(System.now()));
```